# How can I combine 2 tables which enumerate all the possible values in a column

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables in PowerBI

Table1

| Name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

Table 2

| Level |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

I want to create 3rd table in PowerBI which  enumerate all the possible values in a column of each table. i.e. I want to create this

Table 3

| Name | Level |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |

Can you please tell me how this can be done in PowerBI?

Comment: do you know what Google is used for ?

Comment: try to use Google sometimes... start with ``How to Create Joins in DAX with/without Relationships``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table 3 = CROSSJOIN('Table 1','Table 2')
```